# Using MIP SDK how to protect with custom permission

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to apply Protect with Custom Permission on a PDF file using C# MIP SDK. I couldnt find option in MIP SDK to enable custom permission for file. Is there any option available in MIP SDK to apply custom permission. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found the solution to this, but to create your own permissions, you have to create your own protection settings. Here's what I've done

```
public ProtectionDescriptor CreateAdhocDescriptor()
{

    List<UserRights> userRights = new List<UserRights>();

    List<string> viewRights = new List<string>()
    {
        Microsoft.InformationProtection.Protection.Rights.View
    };

    userRights.Add(new UserRights(userEmails, viewRights));

    List<string> printRights = new List<string>()
    {
        Microsoft.InformationProtection.Protection.Rights.Print,
        Microsoft.InformationProtection.Protection.Rights.Comment
    };

    userRights.Add(new UserRights(userEmails, printRights));

    ProtectionDescriptor protectionDescriptor = new ProtectionDescriptor(userRights)
    {
        ContentValidUntil = accessExpiration, 
        AllowOfflineAccess = false
    };


    return protectionDescriptor;
}

ProtectionSettings settings = new ProtectionSettings();
handler.SetProtection(helper.CreateAdhocDescriptor(), settings);
```

Here, handler is the result from fileEngine.CreateFileHandlerAsync. This won't show up in the program your screenshot is from, but it lets up apply a custom set of permissions to the file at the time that you're protecting it.